# simple jquery class array

Tags: jquery, dom

with the dom,

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[2]
```

selects the 3rd element of class `myClass`

in jQuery,

```
$('.myClass')
```

gets class `myClass` but how can I get the 3rd element?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/):

```
 $('.myClass:eq(2)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$('.myClass:eq(2)')` you can also use `$('.myClass').eq(2)` or, if you want a DOM element instead of a jQuery element, `$('.myClass').get(2)`

Comment: what's the difference between jquery and dom elements? aren't they the same thing?

Comment: No. DOM objects are e.g. those returned by document.getElementById and they are usually host objects (-> they can behave as they want - for example, reading an undefined property could throw an exception - and at least in IE they often do so. additionally extending them or their prototype is dangerous).  jQuery objects are pure JavaScript objects which contain one or more DOM objects and metadata (e.g. the selector they used to generate the list)

Comment: A good example for DOM vs jquery is retrieving the ID of an element. Using a jQuery object (containing a single DOM object) you'd use `obj.attr('id')` or `obj[0].id` (the [] subscript operator returns the contained dom objects); using the DOM object you use `obj.id`.

Comment: wow thanks! I learn more and you solidify what you've learned.